# Property test ran as unit test fails even though it really passes

Tags: f#, nunit, fscheck, fsunit

It appears that my property test that's running as a unit test fails even though it really passes.

The code is as follows:

```
module Tests.Units

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open NUnit.Core.Extensibility

open FsCheck.NUnit
open FsCheck.NUnit.Addin
open FsCheck

let add x y = (x + y)

let commutativeProperty x y = 
    let result1 = add x y
    let result2 = add y x // reversed params
    result1 = result2

[<Test>]
let ``When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on parameter order``()=
    Check.Quick commutativeProperty |> should equal true
```

**Summary:**

> Test Name:    When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on
>   parameter order
>
> Test FullName:    Tests.Units.When I add two numbers, the result should
>   not depend on parameter order
>
> Test Outcome: Failed
>
> Result StackTrace:     at
>   FsUnit.TopLevelOperators.should[a,a](FSharpFunc`2 f, a x, Object y) in
>   d:\GitHub\FsUnit\src\FsUnit.NUnit\FsUnit.fs:line 44
>
> at Tests.Units.When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on
>   parameter order()
>
> Result Message:   Expected: true, but was
>
> Result StandardOutput:    Ok, passed 100 tests.

Am I reading this right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Check.QuickThrowOnFailure` instead:

```
[<Test>]
let ``When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on parameter order``()=
    Check.QuickThrowOnFailure commutativeProperty
```

---

Since it looks like you're attempting to run properties from within a unit testing framework like NUnit, you should consider to instead use one of the Glue Libraries for FsCheck:

- [FsCheck.Nunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsCheck.Nunit)
- [FsCheck.Xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsCheck.Xunit)

This would enable you to write properties using the `[<Property>]` attribute:

```
[<Property>]
let ``When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on parameter order``x y =
    let result1 = add x y
    let result2 = add y x // reversed params
    result1 = result2
```

Due to the poor extensibility API for NUnit, you can save yourself a lot of grief using xUnit.net instead of NUnit.